# Mocking HTML Elements in Banckbone for Jasmine Testing

Tags: jquery, templates, backbone.js, jasmine

I am doing Jasmine Unit Testing of `Backbone` Application. I am new to `Jasmine` as well as `Backbone`. My views in the application are created using `BackboneJS` from a HTML Template.

As the application is already deployed. Now I want to test a `Backbone` `view`. For that I need to create a 
mock HTML with some mock data in the `textbox`.

I have this code:

```
that.uoView = new UoView();
that.uoView.render();
$('#sandbox').html(that.uoView.el);
```

in my Jasmine file. This is the only file where I can make any change. It calls a view and holds it in the `$('sandbox')`

As I already have the `HTML` template so I need to populate some mock data in the `HTML` Textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Jquery worked as suggested by rednaw. After writing this code:

```
that.uoView = new UoView();
that.uoView.render();
$('#sandbox').html(that.uoView.el);
```

I added this code:

```
$("#test").val('Test'); //#test is an element in uoView.el
```

And then followed by my specs

Comment: To help people answer your questions in the future, please provide all the relevant code. For example, I don't see an element with id `officeToUnlock` in the question.

Comment: @rednaw: `officeToUnlock` was nothing but an element within `uoView.el`

Answer (score 2):

Usually you initialize your view with an element like this:

```
that.uoView = new UiView({ el: $("#myelement") });
that.uoView.render()
```

Then in the render function you render the html that should come in the `el`:

```
render: function() {
    this.$el.html('my html');
}
```

Every time you call render, the view get's rendered again. You can call render on any html events.

Comment: I have already called my `render` and cannot make any change to my render function. After I have got the values in my `el`. Now I want to make certain changes to the DOM element.

Comment: I said jquery, and maybe first try out yourself before asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could return this after rendering.

```
render: function() {
  this.$el.html('my html');
  return this;
}
```

So you end up with:

```
that.uoView = new UoView();
$('#sandbox').html(that.uoView.render().el);
```

Comment: I have already called my `render` and cannot make any change to my render function. After I have got the values in my `el`. Now I want to make certain changes to the DOM element.

Comment: you can create a function in uoView which describes your DOM change
example: add_tooltip: function(){//do stuff on $el and call this.render()}

Comment: Tht's what I am looking for. But how to do that.? I am new to Backbone how will I do it.?

Comment: you can create a view by extending the view object and then put all your code inside of it.
from the doc:
http://backbonejs.org/#View-extend

Comment: This has already been done.. I am using Jasmine for Unit Testing, there I need to create a mock element, I made it using $el property from an existing HTML Template. Now I need to mock the HTML with some data.

Comment: You should take a look at sinon.js or other equivalents.
http://tinnedfruit.com/2011/03/03/testing-backbone-apps-with-jasmine-sinon.html